# In my code it says x is not defined?

Tags: python

```
def randomcheetahs():
x = random.randint(1,2)
if x == 1:
    r = 'present'
elif x == 2:
    r = 'absent'
return r
```

cheetahs = randomcheetahs()

it says that x==1:
is not defined. How might I go about fixing that?
Tanks

Comment: Is your code actually indented like this ?

Comment: Is there more code? Works for me. edit: Thomas raises a good point. If it's indented like that, it won't work.

Comment: FWIW, the usual way to make the random selection is: ``random.choice(('present', 'absent'))``.

Answer (score 3):

Probably since you didn't use indentation correctly.
Indent every line except the first with 4 spaces.

However I do not have a compiler here so I cannot check it.

Btw but offtopic, your code can be rewritten as:

```
def randomcheetahs(): 
    return 'present' if random.randint(1,2) == 1 else 'absent'
```

Comment: Probably best to leave ternary-ish syntax operations for later if he hasn't even indented his code correctly.

Comment: `return random.choice(['present', 'absent'])`

Answer (score 2):

I guess maybe your code is indented like this

```
def randomcheetahs():
    x = random.randint(1,2)
if x == 1:
    r = 'present'
elif x == 2:
    r = 'absent'
return r

cheetahs = randomcheetahs()
```

You need to indent it like this instead. Be careful not to mix tabs and spaces. It's a good idea to just use spaces

```
def randomcheetahs():
    x = random.randint(1,2)
    if x == 1:
        r = 'present'
    elif x == 2:
        r = 'absent'
    return r

cheetahs = randomcheetahs()
```

As wim says, you can also just do this:

```
def randomcheetahs():
    return random.choice(['present', 'absent'])
```

but it is important for beginners to understand how the indenting works in Python

Comment: Thank you everybody for your help, I was able to get it working by typing it the way wim had it. I appreciate it.